# How could i make the data printed in the list in alphabetical order?

Tags: c, function, linked-list, nodes

The program I was working on was supposed to Add nodes to a linked list, adding each node such that the associated data is kept in alphabetical order. I got it to print however i wanted it to print in alphabetical order for example

!!!

Apple

Bike

Cat

Dog

< ~~~>(put arrows so it wouldn't put it as code)

and so on

i also had another issue, after inputting the second time, when i input the phrase quit it doesn't end the program like it was supposed to, how could i fix that

Thanks

This the current code i had:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
typedef struct IntNode_struct {
    char dataVal[50];
    
    struct IntNode_struct* next;
    
} IntNode;
 
void IntNode_InsertAfter(IntNode* thisNode, IntNode* newNode){
    IntNode *current = thisNode;
    while (current->next != NULL && strcmp(newNode->dataVal, current->next->dataVal) >= 0){
            current = current->next;
        }
        
    newNode->next = current->next;
    current->next = newNode;
    
}
void IntNode_Printlist(IntNode* current){
    
    if(current == NULL)
        return;
    printf("%s\n", current->dataVal);
    IntNode_Printlist(current = current->next);
   
    
    
}
int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {
    IntNode a,b;
    IntNode *head;
    IntNode *current;
   
    
    
    a.next = &b;
    b.next = NULL;
    head = &a;
    strcpy(a.dataVal, "!!!");
    strcpy(b.dataVal, "~~~");
    
    
    while(1){
        current = (IntNode*)malloc(sizeof(IntNode));
        printf("Enter Next Name");
        char dummy[50];
        gets(dummy);
        if(strcmp(dummy, "quit") == 0)
            return 0;
        strcpy(current->dataVal, dummy);
        IntNode_InsertAfter(head, current);
        IntNode_Printlist(head);
        
        printf("\n");
            
            }

        
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Please update the question with what the current (presumably incorrect) behaviour of the program is. If you have already inserted in alphabetical order then printing it should be just traversing the list in order.

Comment: i wanted to figure out how i could get the nodes to print out alphabetically and when i input the phrase quit to end the program

Comment: Change the `return 0;` to `break;` and move the `IntNode_Printlist` to be outside and after the `while` loop. Also, move the `malloc` to be after the quit check to avoid a memory leak. Finally, never use `gets` as that is dangerous and deprecated. Use `fgets` instead.

Comment: thanks it worked, how could i also end the program when i enter the phrase quit

Comment: What do you mean? Do you mean after printing the list? If you don't add any code after printing the list then the program will just end.